# Can't access Linux from macbook

Tags: system-installation, alternate

So I installed linux Elementary OS on my macbook air. I had to do the manual Partitioning since there was no "install alongside" button during installation. The problem is; I can't access it, when I restart it there's no option, I can't choose which operating system I'd like to use.

Comment: Did you use a guide, if so - you certain you followed every step?

Comment: Check out this [article](https://www.elementarynow.com/dual-booting-elementary-os-and-osx/), about rEFInd.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need GUI, boot once with `nomodeset`: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 - then uninstall GUI, and reboot.

You might consider installing directly [Ubuntu (Server) with Alternate ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.4/ubuntu-14.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent), because even [192 MB RAM is enough](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Server_.28CLI.29_Installation) for CLI installation.